# Problems in using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm trying to input some data and compare it with a random average entered by the user.I am entering n,and the data for the first player,but a runtime error occurs and I can no longer enter data.
I create a structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Math.h>
struct player
{
   char name[20];
   int age;
   float average;
};
```

functions are declared to input data and find which avg is closest to avg enterd by user.Pointers are used as arguments

```
void input(struct player *pla,int n);
void close(struct player *pla,int n);
int main()
{
    int n;
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct player pl[n];
    input(&pl[0],n);
    close(&pl[0],n);
}
void input(struct player *pla,int n)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",(&pla[i])->name);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",(&pla[i])->age);
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%f",(&pla[i])->average);

    }
}
void close(struct player *pla,int n)
{
    int av;
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&av);
    int play=abs(pla->average-av);
    int playn=0,i;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(abs((&pla[i])->average-av)<play)
        {
            play=abs((&pla[i])->average-av);
            playn=i;
        }

    }
    printf("%s",(&pla[i])->name);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",(&pla[i])->age);` --> `scanf("%d",&pla[i].age);`, `scanf("%f",(&pla[i])->average);` --> `scanf("%f",&pla[i].average);`

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is illegal. It invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What if I dont want to use the dot(.) operator

Comment: @Olaf But I have to clear the input stream.Otherwise the input stream would stack up and cause problems.

Comment: @NayanGarg: So what does it tell you about your program that you use an inappropriate way? There is no trading with the computer. It does not care that you **want** a function behave a specific way!

Comment: `&pla[i].age` --> `&(pla + i)->age`

Comment: @Olaf why is fflush() illegal anyways if it is a valid function

Comment: @NayanGarg: I did not write that `fflush` invokes UB. What about the man-page is unclear?

Comment: @Olaf sorry I didn't understand

Comment: Read my comments **carefully** again and the man-page of `fflush`!